# 無料サーバでnode.jsを常時実行させるには？

Tags: node.js, twitter

`node.js`を使ってtwitterのbotを作成し、cmd.exeでforeverコマンドを使って実行させています。
しかしこれではPCの電源を落としてしまったら実行できません。当然ですが。
なので無料サーバーを借りて実行させたりしたいのですが、どうすればよいかが全くわかりません。
RubyやPythonが全くわからないので`node.js`で実行させたいです。お願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node.jsが動作する無料サーバーはあまりありません。

質問のようにコマンドで実行させるタイプのものであれば、PaasよりもVPSが便利と思います。VPSであれば、cronで定期的に起動させるか、systemdに組み込んで常時稼働させることができます。VPSの場合は、Google Compute Engine の USリージョンの f1-micro インスタンスが無料で使えますが、それ以外は知りません。

Paasの場合は、Heroku等選択肢はありますが、Webサイト用のものが多く、作成したコードをWebに入れ込む必要があると思います。その場合、長時間かかるような処理はあまり向いていないです。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。調べていったところ、glitchというものが見つかりましたがこれでも大丈夫でしょうか。

Comment: glitchでもできると思いますが、Webアプリ用なのでweb cronサービスを使って定期的に外部から該当のurlを叩いてbotを起動する必要があります。無料のweb cronサービスはあまり融通がきかないので、googleの無料インスタンスでそのサービスを作った方が早いかもしれません。始めてだと結構苦労すると思いますが、無料なのでいろいろ試してみてください。