# node.jsを常時実行させたい

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack

slackを匿名化するbotを作成したく下記のサイトを参考に、node.jsでコードを作成しました。

[Slackで匿名で投稿できるチャンネルを作った - Qiita](https://qiita.com/BIG_LARGE_STONE/items/2edbec562db020167f42)

当たり前ですがこちらのcodeはpcの電源を切ると停止してしまいます。
この処理を常時実行させpcの電源を切ってもSlackを匿名化させたいと考えています。

現在GCP、Glitch、Herokuなどが使えそうだというのはわかりましたが、上記の処理がこれらのサービスで常時実行できるか疑問です。

非常に稚拙な質問で恐れ入りますが、上記の処理を常時行うためにはどうしたらいいかご教授ください。

```js
var Botkit = require("./lib/Botkit.js"); //パス注意
var os = require("os");

var controller = Botkit.slackbot({
    debug: true,
});

var bot = controller.spawn({
    token: "先ほど取得したAPI_TOKEN"
}).startRTM();

controller.on("direct_message", (bot, message) => {
    var now = new Date(); //時刻の取得
    var user_name = "名無しさん: "+ now.getFullYear()+"/"+(now.getMonth()+1)+"/"+now.getDate()+"/ "+now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes()+":"+now.getSeconds();

    bot.reply(message, "匿名で投稿しました．");

    bot.startConversation({  channel : "先ほど取得したチャンネルID" }, (err, convo) => {
        var send_message = {
          type: "message",
          channel: "先ほど取得したチャンネルID",
          text: message.text,
          username: user_name,
          thread_ts: null,
          reply_broadcast: null,
          parse: null,
          link_names: null,
          attachments: null,
          unfurl_links: null,
          unfurl_media: null,
          icon_url: null,
          icon_emoji: ":robot_face:",
          as_user: true
        }
        convo.say(send_message);
    });
});
```

Comment: 重複候補 (回答あり): [無料サーバでnode.jsを常時実行させるには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/48185)

Comment: PCのように電源を着られることが無いクラウドサービス上で実行するなど、物理的に継続稼働している計算機環境を使うしかないのでは？　無料でというのは無理があると思いますが。。。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。　AWSなど試してみます。